# Spring boot not applying Content-Security-Policy defined in Web Security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, content-security-policy

I'm using spring boot `1.5.6.RELEASE` and then I'm not being able to load CSS files in my project.

In console it shows:

> Refused to load the stylesheet
>   'http://localhost:8080/wicket/resource/io.sample/HomePage-ver-1504145057000.css'
>   because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "default-src https:". Note that 'style-src' was not explicitly set, so
>   'default-src' is used as a fallback.

Then I've [found the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/headers.html#headers-csp-configure) and then applied:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.headers()
                .contentSecurityPolicy("default-src 'self'");
    }
}
```

But it is not being written in response headers, as shown by Chrome:

```
Content-Security-Policy:default-src https:
```

But when I change in spring to report only, then it applies to report-only:

Java:

```
   http.headers()
            .contentSecurityPolicy("default-src 'self'")
            .reportOnly();
```

Headers:

```
Content-Security-Policy:default-src https:
Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only:default-src 'self'
```

Do I need to do something else?

Comment: When you tested in Chrome are you sure Chrome wasn’t just loading a stale copy it had cached before you updated the header? If you clear your browser cache in Chrome and try again, does Chrome still show you the `default-src https:` header value instead of `default-src 'self'`?

Comment: Yes, I have cleaned up. Also, when I change the report only to `default-src 'self' http://sometest.com` it shows up immediately.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can add style-src 'self' to your CSP because it's claiming about css error